# Java - Access to remote active directory with linux

Tags: java, linux, active-directory, ldap

my problem is that I had to deploy an application onto a linux server. The authentication is based on a remote active directory. Everything was working fine, but since i have deployed onto the linux server, my authentication no longer works.

This is my authentication code:

```
public boolean connectUser(String login, String password) {



    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, HOST);

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, login+"@nazoos.com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    // Create the initial context
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        Log.getLogger().debug("UserService : Connexion ==> OK ");
        return true;

    } catch (NamingException e) {

        Log.getLogger().debug("UserService : Erreur Connexion :"+e.getMessage());
        return false;

    }


}
```

This is the error that i have

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nazoos.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:368)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203)
    ... 54 more
```

I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @JanTheGun ,i edited my post to add the error message with printStackTrace.

Comment: This is just a DNS failure. Your Linux machine is probably using it's own DNS which has it's ideas about what the proper names for machines are. There is probably a proper hostname for the specific domain controller you want to authenticate against. But using LDAP for authentication in general is not recommended. [Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com/) is currently the best way to authenticate web clients against AD in a Java application. And it has it's own DNS implementation so it will be very good at finding domain controllers and properly failing over to a different server and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HOST variable should have format `ldap://<IP_or_hostname>:389`
2. If you use hostname then you should check that it can be resolved to IP address from your linux server. Maybe you will need to add this hostname into the server hosts file.